# Sum Variables Conditionally in SAS EG

Tags: sas

I am trying to create computed variables in SAS EG.

```
data data1;
    input ID Type Payment_Amt;
    cards;
    1 Voucher $50
    1 Cash $50
    1 Cash $20
    1 Card $20
    1 Card $50
;
```

Data want:

> ID        TotalAmtVoucher        TotalAmtCash        TotalAmtCard
>   1                      $50                      $70                            $70

Is this possible?
Please let me know if I am lacking any details needed.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your input data for `Payment_Amt` is going to be a character variable with a `$` on the front. which is going to be really awkward to work with. I suggest using the numeric amount and using the `dollar`format to display them as monetary values.

However, **if you're data is already in a character format**, you can convert them to numeric with:

```
data data1;
  set data1;
  Payment_Amt2 = input(substr(Payment_Amt,2),best.);

  format Payment_Amt2 dollar3.;

  drop Payment_Amt;
  rename Payment_Amt2 = Payment_Amt;
```

run;

This takes only the values after the `$` in the string using `substr()`and then converts them to numeric values with the `input()` function.

**To get your totals** you can use `proc sql` and then transpose the data:

```
proc sql;
  create table want0 as
  select distinct id, type, sum(payment_amt) as total
  from data1
  group by type;
quit;

proc transpose data = want0 out = want(drop = _name_) prefix = TotalAmt;
  by id;
  id type;
run;
```

The `proc sql` step will sum all the values of a particular `type` via the group by statement. You can then get the data into the format you want with `proc transpose`. The use of the `prefix=` option allows you to specify the `"TotalAmt"` prefix in you variable name.

Answer (score 0):

If the values for Types are known, static, and few you could do the following:

```
data data1;
    input ID : 8. Type : $char10. Payment_Amt : dollar4.;
    cards;
1 Voucher $50
1 Cash $50
1 Cash $20
1 Card $20
1 Card $50
2 Voucher $90
2 Cash $30
;
run;

proc sql;
    create table data_want as
    select ID,
           sum(ifn(Type="Voucher",Payment_Amt,0))   as TotalAmtVoucher format=dollar4.,
           sum(ifn(Type="Cash",Payment_Amt,0))      as TotalAmtCash    format=dollar4.,
           sum(ifn(Type="Card",Payment_Amt,0))      as TotalAmtCard    format=dollar4.
    from data1
    group ID;
quit;
```